# Função explode() em um vetor

Tags: php

Eu recebo uma variável dessa maneira:

```
$VAR = "joao.silva/jose.ferreira/maria.jose/carlos.eduardo/";
```

e preciso armazenar ela dessa forma:

```
$VET = array('joao.silva', 'jose.ferreira', 'maria.jose', 'carlos.eduardo');
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a manipular essa informação para a salvar dessa maneira?

Comment: Não estou a perceber qual é a sua dificuldade, a função explode que indicou retorna o resultado que você pretende. Basta usar explode("/", $string_a_manipular);

Comment: @lazyFox não ha problema em responder a pergunta explicando a utilização da função explode, inclusive ha meu ver nenhuma das respostas abaixo responde efetivamente a pergunta do Rafael, a pergunta mesmo esta mau formulada.... a começar que isso não é  uma variável aceita em php: `$VAR = joao.silva/jose.ferreira/maria.jose/carlos.eduardo/`

Comment: Não coloque a culpa da sua interpretação errada no autor, tanto que a dúvida já foi solucionada e postada :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$VAR = "joao.silva/jose.ferreira/maria.jose/carlos.eduardo/";

// assim você vai ter no arr_nomes todas as ocorrências
$arr_nomes = explode("/",$VAR);

//mostra todos os dados do array
print_r($arr_nomes);

/*
SAÍDA
Array ( [0] => joao.silva [1] => jose.ferreira [2] => maria.jose [3] => carlos.eduardo [4] => ) Nome: joao.silva 

*/

//realiza a leitura de todos os itens do array
foreach($arr_nomes as $nome){

    echo "Nome: $nome </br>"    ;
}

/* SAÍDA 
Nome: jose.ferreira 
Nome: maria.jose 
Nome: carlos.eduardo 
Nome: 
*/
/** Observar que seu delimitador para separação de itens é a "/", 
  então seu último item do array vai estar vazio **/
```

Comment: SHOW DE BOLA! muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

```
   $VAR = joao.silva/jose.ferreira/maria.jose/carlos.eduardo/
   $pieces = explode("/", $VAR);
    echo $piece[0]; //joao.silva
```

Vê se resolve ^^

Answer (score 2):

Use assim `$vet = explode("/", $var);`

Mais [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Comment: Não ha nada de errado em compartilhar links, mas se possivel, puxe a informação que você gostaria de passar para o rapaz que perguntou, para a rede, assim se algum (difícil, mas não impossível) o php.net/manual morrer, a resposta não se tornara obsoleta.